# php increment variable value with 1 when submit

Tags: php, variables, auto-increment

Hi I am new in php and started learning. I am trying to increment variable value with **1** when submit button is pressed.

My Code:

```
<?php
    $i=0;
    if($_POST['submit']){
        echo $i+1;  
    }
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: You need to store that variable somewhere, eg. File, Database or even Session.  What you're doing will always show `1`.

Comment: After this script is run, the variable $i is freed in memory (aka it's gone). The next time you execute the script, PHP has no idea what $i is until you set $i=0. So when you click submit it will always echo 1.

Answer (score 5):

You're variable $i should be stored in session for example, so it won't lost its value when you submit the form. (You can check this answer [Is PHP or PHP based web framework stateful or stateless?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6327314/235659))

Also when your script is executed, the first thing you do is `$i = 0;` so whenever you execute it, you reinitialize the variable to 0.

```
session_start();

// if your variable is not yet defined, you assigned it with 0
if (isset($_SESSION['myVariable']))
{
    $_SESSION['myVariable'] = 0;
}

if($_POST['submit'])
{
    echo $_SESSION['myVariable'] +1;  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
session_start();

    if($_POST['submit']){
        $_SESSION['i'] = isset($_SESSION['i']) ? ++$_SESSION['i'] : 0;
        echo $_SESSION['i'];
    }
?>
```

This will remember the last value between pages

Answer (score 1):

```
var_dump($IsPost = !strcasecmp($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'], 'POST'));
```

^ tells you if it's a post.

```
echo ++$i;
```

^ increments `$I` and then prints `$I`

```
echo $i++;
```

^ prints `$I` and then increments `$I`

```
empty($_POST['submit']); // or isset($_POST['submit']);
```

^ tells you if `['submit']` exists in `$_POST` without notices.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION['i'])) $_SESSION['i'] = 0;
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $_SESSION['i']++;
}
echo $_SESSION['i'];
?>
```