# How to Increment variable with button click , PHP\MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

Button to click

```
 <form action='' method='POST'>
                 <input type='submit' name='submit' />
     </form>
```

Variable to be incremented on button click

```
$currentid="1";
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$sql = "SELECT * from TABLENAME WHERE id='$currentid'  LIMIT 1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["name"].  "<br>";
        //$currentid=$row["id"];
        $currentid=$currentid+1;
        echo "$currentid";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
}
```

Task:

I want to increment `$currentid="1"` by 1 each time the button is clicked.
This will work same like php pagination but just with Next Button. and on each button click next record will be displayed.

I would appreciate if you can suggest any other better way to achieve the same goal.

Comment: Never use `name='submit'` if you ever want to script the form submit - also why use a while if you limit to one row?

Comment: @mplungjan Why not?

Comment: this is just a sample code. off course i will change it in production. I am just looking for logic to acheive the goal

Comment: Because you will break the `form.submi()` if for has an element called submit

Comment: @PhiterFernandes ,, Can you please give an example to achieve the task

Comment: @PhiterFernandes why would a get be better? post will work too.

Comment: I think you need to rethink this - what is currentid? You do not save that. Also you only get one record. You need to save the counter in the session and get the nth record from the sql table

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568/how-to-select-the-nth-row-in-a-sql-database-table

Comment: And use a session var to hold the counter and current id: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17494444/php-increment-variable-value-with-1-when-submit

Comment: GET is better for stuff like pagination

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you know the starting value of currentid when the form is initiated, I would suggest you do this with a hidden input value, that is incremented by Javascript and used as a parameter to the PHP script.

Comment: please give sample code.. I dont know java.

Comment: Java is NOT JavaScript.

Comment: I dont know Javascript as well... :) .. that why i requested a sample code :)

Comment: You do not need JS. You need a session variable and you need to index yourself into your sql table

Comment: masters,, if you can give me sample code,, that will help me under stand the concept better :)